# Table not resizing because of text inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table having some text inside. I have a jQuery script to change the width of table cells to act as slider. The table have 3 square cells bt1, bt2 and bt3. On click, they pushes main cells. In the script, I have set width of active cell to 0px to stretch the other cell. But the text inside is not allowing this to happen.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/RE3jY/2/)** you can see what I am trying to say. Anyone got a fix? Should I add or modify my CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, try this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RE3jY/1/
I changed the layout construction for some floating divs you could not achieve this with table cells.

I kept only the necessary styling, for the demo to work.

hope this helps

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't think this will work with a table, can i refactor the whole thing to work with Divs only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .show() and .hide() after animation complete and show/hide respective content.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fxFk7/1/) here